# How to set a timeout/pause command without a message in batch?

Tags: batch-file

While I was making my small batch game I thought of implementing a "auto dialog" function. Here it is:

```
:Background_Work
SET /p Auto_Text=Would you like to have auto dialog on or off (y/n)?
IF '%Auto_Text%'=='y' GOTO Auto_Yes
IF '%Auto_Text%'=='n' GOTO Auto_No
:Auto_Yes
SET TMode=TIMEOUT /t 7 /nobreak
GOTO Speech_Start
:Auto_No
SET TMode=PAUSE
GOTO Speech_Start
```

Here is what happens after the "auto dialog" function:

```
:Speech_Start
ECHO Hello, my name is ZERO.
%TMode%
```

Everything works, if I were to input "y" then it will display the part under ":Speech_Start" as:

> Hello, my name is ZERO.
>
> Waiting for 7 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit...

and if I were to input "n" then it will display it as:

> Hello, my name is ZERO.
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

The issue I have is, I cant seam to get rid of the TIMEOUT and PAUSE messages. I have tried changing the "auto dialog" function to this:

```
:Background_Work
SET /p Auto_Text=Would you like to have auto dialog on or off (y/n)?
IF '%Auto_Text%'=='y' GOTO Auto_Yes
IF '%Auto_Text%'=='n' GOTO Auto_No
:Auto_Yes
SET TMode=TIMEOUT /t 7 /nobreak > NUL
GOTO Speech_Start
:Auto_No
SET TMode=PAUSE > NUL
GOTO Speech_Start
```

But it still displays the default messages. Anyone know how to get rid of them?

Comment: timeout.... **>nul** or pause **>nul**

Comment: Magoo did you even read the entire post? I said I tried changing it to:
`SET TMode=TIMEOUT /t 7 /nobreak > NUL`
and
`SET TMode=PAUSE > NUL`

Comment: Nope. Read it just as far as the problem appeared to be. Was expecting the current code as the first item. Oh, well. The problem is that `>` is a redirector - a special character. If you were to try `set tmode` before the `%tmode%` you'd see that `tmode` doesn't have the `>nul`. Since `>` is a special character, you need to escape it with a caret if it's not being used as a redirector. Try `SET TMode=PAUSE ^> NUL` or preferably `SET "TMode=PAUSE ^> NUL"` (the quotes ensure unwanted trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned).

Comment: Howabout   **%TMODE% >nul**   at :Speech_Start ?

Comment: ohhh... ok. Thanks Magoo.

Answer (score 1):

As @Magoo says, in your second code snippet, there were two issues that are related to the `timeout` redirection.

---

```
SET TMode=TIMEOUT /t 7 /nobreak > NUL
SET TMode=PAUSE > NUL
```

In this case `> NUL` was used to redirect the `set` prompt to `nul`, and was not a part of the command. Now the batch file sees `TMode` as:

```
TIMEOUT /t 7 /nobreak
```

or

```
PAUSE > NUL
```

---

Solution A:
Suggested by @Magoo

```
set "TMode=timeout /t 7 /nobreak ^> nul"
```

This solution escapes the `>` charactor, making `> nul` a part of the variable, not the redirection operator.

Solution B: Suggested by @PualH

```
%TMode% > nul
```

Very simple; just redirect the command output to `nul`. Note there is one con:

- If you want to use multiple of these commands, you need to repeat `> nul` multiple times.